# how to load an alert inside an if statement twig

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig

i want to load an alert from js script that should only run if the condition is met:

Code:

```
{% if user_perm.up_slug != "view_hospitals" %} 
<!-- <frame id="info" onload="errorLoad()"></frame> --> 
<!-- <div id="info" onload="errorLoad()"></div> --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        errorLoad();
        function errorLoad()
        {
            $.confirm({
                icon: 'fa fa-question-circle-o',
                theme: 'supervan',
                closeIcon: true,
                animation: 'scale',
                type: 'orange',
                title: 'Sorry',
                content: "Your not permitted to view this page",
                buttons: {
                    "Go Home": function () {
                        window.location.replace('{{ base_url() }}/dashboard');
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    </script>
{% else %} ... {% endif %}
```

i know onload doesnt work on div, but what i want is if the condition is met on the if statement, then the script pops up an alert.

what i want is **i want the function errorLoad() to run when the if condition is met**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want the function errorLoad() to run when the if condition is met

Comment: With the example u've posted it will, see (simplyfied version) [here](https://twigfiddle.com/f9vb5c)

Comment: thank you. i used your example and it worked